# Find the polygon area on a sphere bounded by points

Tags: polygon, spherical-coordinate, geodesic-sphere

I am trying to find the area of a polygon on a sphere. I have the azimuth and elevation angles (lat/lon). Is there an algorithm that will do this. If it were on a flat plane, I could approximate using a convex hull, but these points are occupying a significant portion of the sphere.

Comment: Interesting problem!  If nobody gives you an answer here, it might be worth asking on math.stackexchange.com.